# Showing NaN to NaN in jquery bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have integrated jquerydatatable in bootstrap framework and when i select All it is showing like this

Showing NaN to NaN of 7 entries.

Javascript

```
$(function () {


    $('#example2').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 50, "All"]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html):

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
});
```

So, add two arrays, one with values and one with the texts shown.

(-1 seem to be equal to "All" in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its working for me:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example2').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        });
 });
```